# PyCharm not using newest version of pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I would like to preface that I am very inexperienced with programming and I am probably going to use some incorrect terminology, so bear with me. I am pissed off at bots buying out stock of graphics cards in seconds, leaving me unable to buy any, so I've decided to fight fire with fire. I will not be scalping graphics cards. I have morals.

When I run `py -m pip install --upgrade pip` in the terminal, it returns `Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\awsmcube\pycharmprojects\3060tibot\venv\lib\site-packages (21.0.1)`. When I run `py -m pip --version`, it returns `pip 21.0.1 from C:\Users\AWSMcube\PycharmProjects\3060tibot\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`.

However, when I try running `pip install Scrapy`, it returns a long error code: `Command "C:\Users\AWSMcube\PycharmProjects\3060tibot\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AWSMcube\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-97nzwr21\\cryptography\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read() .replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AWSMcube\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4yro5d1x\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\AWSMcube\PycharmProjects\3060t ibot\venv\include\site\python3.7\cryptography" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AWSMcube\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-97nzwr21\cryptography\`, along with this suggestion: `You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 21.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.` This brings me back to upgrading pip, which I have done as seen in the previous paragraph.

Why is it telling me that I am using pip version 10.0.1 when I already installed pip version 21.0.1? I have already tried restarting PyCharm.

Comment: I see that you have tried: `py -m pip --version`. So perhaps you should try: `py -m pip install Scrapy`?

Comment: @quamrana well, that works, thank you <3